# How can I take shaped object data to make into a XML document and validate via Schema?

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have a series of domain entities, let's say the following:

- Customer (Customer has Order)
- Order (Order has Product)
- Product

Now the data as it stands in the object graph *does not* match the .xsd. Therefore I don't believe I can just serialize the object graph to XML as it may not match the .xsd. However please correct me on this if I'm wrong. So I have a few questions:

1. Generically speaking, how do I take data from an object or collection which I may need to manually traverse and build a XML document? Can I use LINQ to XML (using XElement) as I understand XPath was an older technology? I've used LINQ to XML before to read and query XML documents, but wonder about building XML documents using it.
2. How do I validate the built XML document against the schema using the suggested approach from #1 after it is built?

Any direction on this is appreciated, thanks!